# SPFX and react-router

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I'm having trouble getting react-router working on my SharePoint Web Part with React and TypeScript.  I have tried react-router as a standalone webapp and it works fine.  Just can't get it working on SharePoint.  When I run my Web Part in my local machine with react-router, I get a blank screen and no errors.  I searched for answers all over and can't find anything that works.  Below is a HelloWorld Web Part example where I have put in 'Router' and 'Route' tags to see if it would work.  When I run this, it shows a blank screen.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { IHelloWorldProps } from './IHelloWorldProps';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, hashHistory  } from "react-router-dom";

export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component<IHelloWorldProps, {}> {
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IHelloWorldProps> {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <Route path="/" component={HelloWorld}/>
        </Router>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

If anyone could help or point me in the right direction in terms of documentation, I would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is Typescript. Are you using .dts definition files for react router?

Comment: Forgot to mention TypeScript.  I'll update my question.  I don't think I'm using a definition file for React Router.  I'm not getting any errors on my editor.  When I run the app, there are no errors in the console window.  There are warnings but seems unrelated.  Do I need this?  If yes, how do I add it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following command:

**npm install --save @types/react-router**

Then, if you see any errors try fixing them. Then re run the application.

Comment: I installed @type/react-router and run the application.  No errors in the terminal and no errors in the console.  The Web Part shows a blank screen.  Anything else I should try?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new component to use in that route, instead of using the same HelloWorld component inside the HelloWorld component.